# Xubuntu doesn't recognize when hdmi receiver is plugged in (but normal hdmi screen works!)

Tags: xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

As the title says, my Xubuntu 17.10 will output video and audio through HDMI as long as I directly plug my screen in, but it never realizes a cable has been plugged in when I try it with my receiver.

The Windows 7 HDMI -> receiver -> TV setup works from another laptop.

The setup with Xubuntu HDMI -> receiver -> TV doesn't realize anything is plugged in.

Changing sound profiles in pulseaudio doesn't do anything (all unplugged).

What's going on? I'm not sure what output to give that could be helpful :)

EDIT:

Hardware and software info:

- My receiver is a Harman Kardon AVR160 (shows up as AVR160/1600 with my Windows laptop connected). I found a firmware update on their website, but their newest version was already on my receiver.
- My laptop is a new Acer Aspire ES11 : ES1-132-C2JZ. As far as I can tell, the graphics card should be an Intel 520. The graphics driver is intel's i915 (hda) driver, but I've tried using Xubuntu's default driver which didn't change anything. aplay -l lists the audio card as "PCH[HDA Intel PCH, device 0: ALC255 Analog" and then prints a bunch of "PCH[HDA Intel PCH, device x: HDMI y [HDMI y]". Which I'm guessing are HDMI sound profiles and not actual cards(?).
- Not sure if it is relevant, but the TV at the other side of the receiver is an old (2009) HD-ready tv: LG 42PQ2000. I've tried without the TV connected and either way, this setup works from my Windows laptop.

lshw output (with info about USB, network and some details about the processor and ram removed for formatting reasons):

```
description: Notebook
    product: Aspire ES1-132 (Aspire ES1-132_110C_1.15)
    vendor: Acer
    version: V1.15
    serial: removed :D
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: chassis=notebook family=APL sku=Aspire ES1-132_110C_1.15 uuid=79DE4B1A-04BD-47B1-8EC0-A81E84BCF3AE
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Ornith_AP_S
       vendor: APL
       physical id: 0
       version: V1.15
       serial: NBGHN110027351E5597600
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Insyde Corp.
          physical id: 0
          version: V1.15
          date: 07/11/2017
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 4544KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3350 @ 1.10GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3350 @ 1.10GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 929MHz
          capacity: 2400MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz      
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Host Bridge
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0b
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 0.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:00.1
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:24 memory:91310000-91317fff
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:371 memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0e.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:374 memory:91318000-9131bfff memory:91000000-910fffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Trusted Execution Engine
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0f.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:372 memory:9131e000-9131efff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 0b
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:369 memory:9131c000-9131dfff memory:91327000-913270ff ioport:2080(size=8) ioport:2088(size=4) ioport:2060(size=32) memory:91325000-913257ff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port A #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 13
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
             version: fb
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:120
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port A #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 13.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.2
             version: fb
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:121 ioport:1000(size=4096) memory:91200000-912fffff

        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port A #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 13.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.3
             version: fb
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 memory:91100000-911fffff

        *-generic:1
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:31 memory:91321000-91321fff memory:91322000-91322fff
        *-generic:2
             description: SD Host controller
             product: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series eMMC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:39 memory:91323000-91323fff memory:91324000-91324fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Low Pin Count Interface
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 0b
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.1
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:91326000-913260ff ioport:2040(size=32)
```

Comment: Can you give us the makes and models of your computer and "receiver"?

Comment: Added some software and hardware info.

Answer (score 0):

Switched my two HDMI cables around for the lulz. Immediately worked. Both setups work now. I don't understand why though...